# Signing a shaded jar using Maven

Tags: maven, code-signing

I am using the Maven shade plugin to make an uber jar, and would like to use the jarsign plugin to sign it.  It appears that the jarsign plugin is being run before the shade plugin, so my final jar is not being signed.  Any ideas??

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, set the `<phase>` of the jarsign plugin to be either the same one as the shade plugin, or a later one. Also, please be advised, that the plugins in Maven are on a FIFO basis, meaning that if you a have plugin defined before another one in the xml and both plugins are to execute in the same phase, the one defined first will be executed first.

Comment: Good to know! I had no idea about FIFO.

Comment: Do you know what phase I should use?

Comment: the shaded jar does retain signatures from the original jar unless you've filtered them out for some reason. Or if you're pulling in unsigned classes or classes with different signatures you'll want to change the phase to verify